# Keep current location (Bluedot image) moving in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using `Google Maps V2`. I have added 2 `markers` A, B (with custom drawable) and a `route` between them. Everything is working well, but I want to keep the `Blue Dot` (current location resource) with default animation and blue circle in my `maps`, when I move, this `Blue Dot` is moving between 2 markers. Is this possible or how to create `Blue Dot` marker like `map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a mistake when `setMyLocationEnabled = false`. So set it `true` and my problem is solved.